# sql for Active and Inactive status

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a sql to get the below result:

```
  Case No: 1          Status:Inactive
    Case No: 2          Status:Active
    Case No: 2          Status:Inactive
    Case No: 3          Status:Active
```

The sql is :

```
select Case No, 
Case when status in ( 'Hospital', 'Discharge') then 'Inactive' else 'Active' end as status
from Cases
```

If for the case no, for example case no 2, there are diffrent status : Inactive and Active, then status is inactive. 
How can I modify the Sql to get the following result?

```
Case No :1              Status:Inactive
Case No :2              Status:Inactive
Case No: 3              Status:Active
```

Comment: There are many ways to accomplish this but it depends on your actual table structure. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Status is varchar type, I cannot use either sum() or Max()

Answer (score 2):

Given the names you have for your statuses, it seems to be sufficient to use `max()`:

```
select CaseNo, 
       max(Case when status in ( 'Hospital', 'Discharge') then 'Inactive' else 'Active'
           end) as status
from Cases
group by CaseNo;
```

A more general solution that doesn't depend on the lexicographical ordering of the names is:

```
select CaseNo, 
       (case when sum(status in ('Hospital', 'Discharge')) > 0
             then 'Inactive'
        else 'Active'
           end) as status
from Cases
group by CaseNo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below query

```
Select [Case No],
CASE MAX(Status) WHEN 0 THEN 'active' ELSE 'Inactive' END Status 
FROM
(
 select [Case No], 
   CASE WHEN  status in ( 'Hospital', 'Discharge') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END status
  from Cases ) C
group by [Case No]
```

**[SQL demo link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/810ff/2)**

**See screenshot**
[image]

Comment: @Cindy Added sql fiddle link. Please do click and try modifying values on left side, build schema and rerun query.

Comment: Thank you so much!